# Possible to block elements WITHIN Flash?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, flash-player, adblock

I'm guessing this is pretty much impossible, but thought I'd ask.

I know you can block whole flash elements with things like AdBlock, but was wondering if there was a way you could block elements, such as images, WITHIN a flash file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block, no.  Some elements are packaged within the flash object while some are loaded from external sources.

You can use javascript to control some elements of a flash object, but you'd have to know a lot about the flash object to do this such as specific names or ids of the components.

Check this page out for some examples - http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

Comment: I thought as much...... thanks for the confirmation! :)